# regex matching string in between string

Tags: javascript, python, regex, string, match

I have always found regex hard. I am sorry but I had to ask,

```
https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt?authuser=1
https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt
https://meet.google.com/zzz44-5454ws-fgaf
```

How would I get the code, for instance `zzz44-5454ws-fgaf` or `zzz-tssd-trt` or `zzz-tssd-trt` from these strings?

Comment: Why is your Q tagged JavaScript AND python? Surely you don't need a solution in both languages.

Comment: my bad. I have removed them.

Comment: [\w-]+(?=\?|$) this selects the 1 at the end as well, the 1 in authuser=1.

Comment: and does not select anything from ```https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt```

Comment: `(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=\?|$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'https://meet.google.com/[a-z0-9]{3}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{3}','gi'`
this is more restrictive and worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Regex. Much safer to use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const paths = `https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt?authuser=1
https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt
https://meet.google.com/zzz44-5454ws-fgaf`
 .split(/\n/).map(url => new URL(url).pathname)

console.log(paths)
```

Comment: i have used this but thought i would try with regex as well. thanks for this

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `\w(?=/)/([^?|\n]+)` this regwx will group all the charctes after the last `/` and before `?` or new line.

```
import re

s = """
https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt?authuser=1
https://meet.google.com/zzz-tssd-trt
https://meet.google.com/zzz44-5454ws-fgaf
"""

print(re.findall(r"\w(?=/)/([^?|\n]+)", s))
```

Output

```
['zzz-tssd-trt', 'zzz-tssd-trt', 'zzz44-5454ws-fgaf']
```